# mod_wsgi and aws access keys

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mod-wsgi, boto3

I got a Flask app which runs under Apache and mod_wsgi.
It needs to read from AWS S3, so I use boto3.
What I did is ran **aws configure** to create ~/.aws and then moved it to 
home configured for WSGI. But when I run application I get:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

If I set the keys in WSGI app startup file as `os.environ['AWS_....'] = ...` it works correctly.

So the question is how to make use of aws configure output in terms of Flask app running under mod_wsgi?

Answer (score 0):

Set AWS_PROFILE environment variable at the OS level. In Linux you would create the variable in '/etc/environment'

AWS_PROFILE=myprofile

Alternatively you could create an IAM Role for the instance profile and provide proper permissions that way.

Comment: But why doesn't boto3 see the contents of ./aws when is being run from WSGI module?